# Proving polynomial to be subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V=$P_5$(R) = all the polynomials with real coefficients of degree at most 5. 
Let `U={rx+rx^4|rϵR}`

(1) Prove that U is a subspace.
(2) Find a subspace W such that V=U⊕W

For the first proof, I know that I have to show how this polynomial satisfies the 3 conditions in order to be a subspace but I don't know how to show this.

I am utterly confused with both of the problems. I read the textbook which confused me even more. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose two polynomials $f_1$ and $f_2$ are in your space, you need to show that $sf_1+f_2$ is in your space, where $s_1 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, let $f_1=rx+rx^4$ and $f_2=tx+tx^4$, then $sf_1+f_2=(sr+t)x+(sr+t)x^4$, so this polynomial is indeed in $U$.

So, $U$ is a subspace.

Now, hints to find a $W$: can you choose $W$ to be the set of polynomials of degree less than $5$, with $x$ and $x^4$ terms missing? If not, how can you "modify" the previous $W$?

Comment: Then what about 0 belonging to U? How do I prove that?
As for finding V, can it be rx^2+rx^2?

Comment: @user720329: $0 \in U$ is trivial. Take $r=0$. Your choice of $W$ isn't correct. $W$ has to be such that $U+W=V$ as sets first.

Comment: Is W=0? I'm not sure

Comment: @user720329: no. $W=0$ if and only if $U=V$. You should look up the definition of direct sum.

Comment: Is it just r since the utmost degree is 5?